# How to update nested field object without updating whole object dynamically in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
name: { type: String, default: null },
contacts: {
  mobileNumber: {
    countryCode: { type: String, default: null },
    digits: { type: String, default: null }
  },
  email: { type: String, default: null },
  facebook: { type: String, default: null },
  googlePlus: { type: String, default: null },
  twitter: { type: String, default: null },
  linkedin: { type: String, default: null }
}}, { timestamps: true });
```

I want to update only the specific nested fields of this schema. For that what I does is,

```
 updateUser: function (userId, patchObject) {
  var conditions = { "_id": userId };
  User.update(conditions,{$set:patchObject});
}
```

But the problem is if the patchObject is **{contacts:{email:"abc@aaa.com"}}** it updates the email correctly but it replace the whole contacts object where I loose all the predefined values for other fields. (ex: facebook)

What Google suggests is this,

```
User.update(conditions,{"contacts.email":"abc@aaa.com"});
```

But the problem is I need a dynamic way to do it for any kind of object. I cannot hardcode all the possible values.  **Is there any way to dynamically update a nested field without replacing other stuff ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the best and easiest way to do these kind of updates in mongoose is to use the `save()` method. It lets you handle the mongodb records as plain javascript objects, so on my node website I try to:

```
    User.findOne( { email: email },
      (err, user) => {
      // modify your "data", probably with a callback chain
```

at some other function, you can `user.save()`. Ofcourse, there is `$set` workaround but its more of an overkill if you just want to get a simple update done for your users. With this approach I could even use `async` library to chain a series of updates on a user record during onboarding painlessly.

Comment: But again u have to do two i/o operations right? One to retrieve and one to write?

Comment: Yes but if you are using mongoose, it internally does much worse than the overhead of reading a few more bytes into memory. Your mongodb record is abstracted out as a plain javascript which is very [costly](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L173).